# Train/subway accelerometer data, with line/stations metadata (train rider's smartphone OK)

Tags: transportation, public-transport, accelerometer

I need accelerometer history taken by people riding urban trains or subway.

Ideally more than 10 minutes of riding, and more than 20 samples for each train line.

The name of the train line, and the time at which each station is reached, should be available for each file.

Some noise will probably result from people handling their phones or moving a bit in the subway, that is not a problem.